# Pandas pivot table reversing the date order

Tags: pivot-table

I have a dataframe which I pivot and I need to understand how I can reverse the order of the dates, so the most recent date is first.

E.g.
Title  Date         Close

0   ABBA.  29/01/2021   164.34

1   ABBA.  28/01/2021   154.34

2   ABBA.  27/01/2021   144.34

3   ABBA.  26/01/2021   134.34

4   ABBA.  25/01/2021   124.34

5   ABBA.  24/01/2021   114.34

When I pivot it
ptable = dff.pivot_table(index=['Title'], columns='Date', values='Close')

I get :

Title           24/01/2021        25/01/2021   26/01/2021

ABBA            114.34.           124.34.      134.34

What I want is:

Title      29/01/2021   28/01/2021   27/01/2021

ABBA       164.34.      154.34.      144.34

I can't seem to see how?

Answer (score 1):

Since the data is correct you only need to reindex your columns in your desired order. Try this:

```
pcolumns = list(ptable.columns)
pcolumns.reverse()
ptable[pcolumns]
```

Alternatively, you use `.sort_index()`.

```
ptable.sort_index(ascending=False, axis=1)
```

Comment: Its still coming out the same. If I type out ptable.info() I get the following: #   Column               Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------               --------------  -----  
 0   2021-01-04 00:00:00  3 non-null      float64

Comment: Aha! I applied your sort_index to the actual create pivot_table command and that worked! Thank you so much - I've literally searched for hours looking for an example and didn't find one.

Comment: ptable = dff.pivot_table(index=['Title'], columns='Date', values='Close').sort_index(ascending=False, axis=1) worked.